# Django: error de url al guardar un registro desde admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

os comento mi problema.

Estoy desplegando una web (Python 3.4 y Django 2.0.4), ya ha guardado datos en varios modelos desde el panel de administrador logueado como superuser, pero al llegar a una app llamada About, con un modelo del mismo nombre, me está saltando este error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://www.myweb.com/admin/about/about/add/

Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.options.add_view
Using the URLconf defined in myweb.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
busqueda/
contacto/
sobre-mi/
admin/
[name='home']
<slug:categoria>/ [name='category']
<slug:category>/<slug:slug>/ [name='post']
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, about/about/add/, didn't match any of these.
```

Este modelo tiene un campo ImageField, en los que había guardado hasta ahora este campo no existe, he probado con otro modelo con este campo y me salga el mismo error.

Este es myproject/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
        path('busqueda/', include('search.urls')),
        path('contacto/', include('contact.urls')),
        path('sobre-mi/', include('about.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('post.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Y el about/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import AboutView

app_name = 'about'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', AboutView.as_view(), name='about-me'),
]
```

Tiene pinta de ser un error de principiante, pero soy incapaz de solucionarlo. Gracias.

**EDITO**: Borrando el campo ImageField del modelo sí me ha dejado grabarlo.

Comment: tienes dos about en ademas que la url la estas importando como sobre-mi , la url quedaria mas o menos asi `http://www.myweb.com/sobre-mi/add/`

Comment: ¿El primer about no hace referencia a la app y el segundo al modelo? Respecto a lo de sobre-mi, tengo la intención de que esa sea la url, pero el error lo genera desde myweb.com/admin al añadir un about. No sé si estoy en lo cierto o no estoy entendiendo path

Comment: @JackNavaRow sí lo abre como /admin/app/modelo/add de hecho, nada más acceder a la pantalla de Django, ya se puede ver esa ruta.

Comment: 'path('admin/', admin.site.urls)' este path ponlo primero por lo menos en django 1.11 y anteriores suele dar errores

Comment: @JimyHendrixFalcónCárdenas tampoco funciona, pero gracias

Comment: lo que también puede estar dando error es que el nombre del APP es el mismo que el de la aplicación , lo que tendrias que hacer es cambiar el nombre de la aplicaciones

Comment: ¡Solucionado! La empresa con la que contraté el hosting (dinahosting), sólo ofrece soporte para python3.4 y la versión de Django que utilizaba, requería, como mínimo, python 3.5, yo en local lo desarrollé con python 3.6. Ojo con la web oficial de django, pone que la versión 2 tiene compatibilidad con la 3.4, pero si mirais la nota install del repositorio de GitHub de Django dice que necesita obligatoriamente 3.5 o superior.

Comment: Por cierto, es la primera vez que he utilizado esta plataforma, ¿tengo que hacer algo con la pregunta, como marcarla, cerrarla o editarla de alguna forma? Gracias a todos los que os habéis preocupado en responder para ayudarme. Un saludo.

Comment: lo ideal es que te autorespondas o cerrar esta pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en la versión de python (3.4), no era compatible con la de Django que me ofrecía la empresa de hosting (dinahosting). He probado con otro proveedor (guebs.com), que me deja instalar python 3.6 y me ha funcionado a la primera.

Answer (score 0):

Estos son los pasos a seguir para cambiar la versión de Python instalada por defecto en el servidor:

1 - Accede vía SSH a tu hosting.
2 - Crea un directorio para la instalación local de la versión de Python que necesitas y accede a ese directorio. En nuestro ejemplo el directorio se llamará nuevodir.

```
mkdir nuevodir
cd nuevodir
```

3 - Descarga la versión de Python que quieres utilizar, en nuestro caso hemos elegido Python 3.6.10, puedes encontrar la versión que prefieras en el repositorio oficial de Python.

4 - Descomprime el fichero que has descargado y accede al nuevo directorio que se ha generado

```
tar xvf Python-3.6.10.tar.xz
cd Python-3.6.10
```

5 - Ejecuta los siguientes comandos para realizar la instalación de forma local. La ejecución de cada uno de ellos puede llevar unos minutos.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local --exec-prefix=$HOME/.local --enable-optimizations
make -j 8
make install
```

Con esto quedaría todo listo y podrás disfrutar de tu versión de Python, para comprobarlo simplemente sitúate en el directorio raíz de tu hosting y ejecuta lo siguiente

```
 cd ~
 .local/bin/python3 --version
```

Este comando obtiene la versión de Python que has instalado localmente.

Fuente: [dinahosting](https://dinahosting.com/ayuda/usando-version-personalizada-python/)